# Word interop adding text from one paragraph to the next keeping formatting

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have two consecutive paragraphs, the second has some text formatted italics. I add the text of the second paragraph to the first by setting the range of the first paragraph then using this code:

```
Paragraph nextPar = firstPar.Next();
Range nextRange = nextPar.Range;
firstRng.InsertAfter(nextRange.Text.ToString());
```

This works well but it removes the italic from the text of the second paragraph. I want a way to keep formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Italics (or bold or any other style) is applied to the whole range. With `InsertAfter`, you are just putting more text in the same range and thus implicitly accepting the given format. You have to rely on two different ranges to allow italics/non italics.

Just keep adding paragraphs and account for as many different ranges as different styles you want. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628473/different-format-into-one-single-line-interop-word) you have examples showing how to include different styles (ranges) in the same line.

Comment: Thanks for help and reply. But it is the Italics from the second parapgraph that i want to keep. The text that i add to the firstRng. Maybe i misunderstand you. Also, the whole range is not italics so making it italic is not i what i need, thanks.

Comment: No, I was the one misunderstanding your question. In this case, you cannot rely on the same range. When you do InsertAfter you are just extending the first range and this range can have italics or not, but not both. Sorry about the misunderstanding (answering too quickly have this kind of things ;)), you can read my new answer.

Comment: I have updated my resply again with a link giving some alternatives to include different styles in the same line.